# How to add dictionaries to tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'm new to python. I have tuple. It's have a elements /dictionaries/. I need a add new dictionaries to tuple? How to do it? I'm using python 2.7. Thank you for every help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Chris Gregg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950692/how-to-add-dictionaries-to-tuple/6950703#6950703) said, you can't add *anything* to a tuple that already exists. You can add two tuples to create a new one though.

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> t + (d,)
(1, 2, 3, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2})
```

The old tuple remains the same:

```
>>> t
(1, 2, 3)
```

You could also do this:

```
t += (d,)
```

which is shorthand for

```
t = t + (d,)
```

Comment: That is what I want. Thank you very much. You save my day.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add anything to a tuple, as it is immutable.  In order to add a dictionary to a *new* tuple, you simply put them into parenthesis, separated by commas:

```
myTuple = (dict1, dict2, dict3)
```

Comment: This way is create a tuple with dictionaries. I need if tuple's existed how to add a dictionaries to it?

Comment: You cannot add anything to a tuple without creating a new tuple (you should probably be using lists if you want to add to them).  If you really want a new tuple with the addition of your old tuple, you can do this: `myTuple += (anotherDict,)`

Answer (score 1):

Why use a tuple ? they are made so you cannot add new values after you define it you can only "summon" a new one .
And if you already have a tuple you can transform your tuple in to a list to for the exchange period .

```
d = {'a':'val1' , 'b': 'val2'}
tuple1 = ( 1 , 2 , 3 )
list1 = list(tuple1).append(d)
```

this way you can use the list if you ever want to add something new to it and summon some other tuple.
and if you really want it to be a tuple back use the tuple function .

```
tuple2 = tuple(list1)
```

Any way i hope you got the point of lists and tuples .